# Do Neural Networks tend to have Zero Mean Errors in each Output?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, datasets, probability-distribution, approximation-error

My NN (a few linear layers with ReLUs + batch normalization, no activation in the last layer) learns to approximate vector-valued labels $y_z$ from data $z\sim\rho_z$ in a supervised way, i.e. net$(z)=y'_z\approx y_z$. I was wondering if there exists any literature that investigates the distribution of the error in each component of the output, i.e. the distribution of $(y'_z)_i-(y_z)_i$. Ideally, I want this to have zero mean, i.e.

$$
\mathbb{E}_{z\sim\rho_z}[(y'_z)_i-(y_z)_i]=0.
$$

Do any such results exist, or probably also results that suggest this is not typically the case?

Comment: The formula you show is exactly the loss function that you optimize in training, so ideally this should be zero mean in any case. It sounds like you might be interested in the field of optimization theory. There are results but not much that you can easily apply in practice - that's why it's theory^^ Besides that I don't really understand what you mean by 'distribution of the error in each component of the output'. What are 'components' here? If you mean dimensions, then you won't find a concrete answer, as this is task-specific and you cannot make universal assumptions about that.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about dimensions (i.e. first entry of the vector, second, etc.). And yes, ideally, it should not just be zero mean, but actually zero :D but as there will always be some error, I was wondering if there are results on how it usually behaves. I've checked the literature, but only found results on the absolute error, not on it's expecatition w.r.t. the data distribution...